# How to insert and update in cursor loop with auto_increment

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have attempted looking through many of the topics already and have no success if figuring out what is wrong with my syntax.  I am trying to take the distinct value of one table and loop insert into another table while the id is auto_incrementing.  Here is what I have so far and I can not seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.  I have 2 procedures written.  They both "work" but don't.

Thank you for your help!

Basically I am trying to insert from one table to another, and use the AUTO_INCREMENT to generate my build_id.  The table I want to populate is:

```
permits.build_type

build_id      INT             PK
build_desc    VARCHAR(200)
```

and the code is:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE building_list()
BEGIN
  DECLARE output VARCHAR(200);
  DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT DISTINCT BUILDING_TYPE 
        FROM permits.edmonton_upto_10may2016_mostly_text;

  OPEN my_cursor;  
  BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND BEGIN END; 
    LOOP
      FETCH my_cursor INTO output; 
      INSERT INTO permits.build_type (build_desc) VALUES (output);
      UPDATE permits.build_type SET build_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END LOOP;
  END;
  CLOSE my_cursor;
END//
```

Comment: Hello yes thank you so much!  How silly the answer is so simple.... I totally face palmed when I read your answer...

Comment: glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a simple INSERT SELECT?

```
INSERT INTO built_type(build_desc)
SELECT DISTINCT BUILDING_TYPE 
    FROM permits.edmonton_upto_10may2016_mostly_text;
```

Comment: Sorry new to MySQL and mainly from Oracle PLSQL and so I was understanding it as that I needed to loop it while the auto_increment goes in or if I do that insert select, the auto increment will just populate?  I do no have to call it or anything?

Comment: when you put a null in an auto column, it gets replaced by the next auto increment value.